# How do I stop the Google app from automatically updating?

Tags: google, application-autoupdate

On my Samsung Galaxy A10E, Android 10 the [Google app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) will update, taking up 300 Mb of unnecessary data, despite these things I tried:

- Disabling the app (It re-enables itself after updating)
- Disabling all permissions
- Disabling Google Play Services permissions
- Disabling auto updates in Google Play Store

I don't really need those 300 Mb, but I hate that this app is acting outside of its permissions. Can this be stopped?

Comment: Yes the search app

Comment: On my A10 I simply uninstalled it.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Chenmunka I have tried, but on my device there is no uninstall option. Instead, there is the option to disable the app. In the Google Play Store, I can uninstall the updates to the app, but even with automatic downloads disabled, the Google app will update itself to the 300 MB version without notifying at all.

Comment: Same for Huawei Y6 II Dual :/ Hope someone will find a solution

Comment: its a hige pain .. nexus6 no unistall & when i disable it cant use my phone.. get the tumbling hr glass ..google apps constant snooping consumes battery.. the updating seems to be run from google launcher.. & nexus6 has no options to control it.. battery life doubles with update removed but its back after 24hrs

Comment: Well if Google app isn't important for you, you can uninstall it using the following ADB command `adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`